# Alternative to innerthtml

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently attaching html tags to a div using innerHTMl using server side C#. At this point, I am a little bit concerned about innerHTML not been enconded and this might lead to some security exploits.

```
 var myRequestCount = client.GetRequests(id);
        var myRequestMsgs = client.GetRequests(id).OrderByDescending(rd => rd.CreatedDate).Take(4);
        lblNoOfRequests.Text = myRequestCount.Count().ToString();
        if (myRequestMsgs.Count() != 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<ul style='list-style-type:disc !important'>");
            foreach (var requestMsgs in myRequestMsgs)
            {

                sb.Append("<a href='#' onclick='return openMyRequestRadWindow(" + requestMsgs.RequestNo + " );' style='color:#f60;font-size:12px;line-height:0.5em'>" + MyZimraHelpers.TruncateAtWord(requestMsgs.Subject, 50) + "</a><br/>");

            }

            myRequestContainer.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            myRequestContainer.InnerHtml = "No Request was found";
            dvMyRequestVwMore.Visible = false;
        }
        client.Close();
```

If I use server.htmlencode(sb.Tostring()) everything comes out as plain html tags in the browser same as using innertext. What is the best way to encode the above output.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: you really should not be mixing HTML, CS, JavaScript and CSS in single line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your loop inside the view itself rather than injecting html into the controls from the codebehind. I use this pattern regularly.

```
<% foreach (var requestMsgs in myRequestMsgs)
    { %>
        <a href="#"
           onclick="return openMyRequestRadWindow(<%= requestMsgs.RequestNo %>);"       
           style="color:#f60; font-size:12px; line-height:0.5em; " >
           <%= MyZimraHelpers.TruncateAtWord(requestMsgs.Subject, 50) %>
        </a><br/>
 <% } %>
```

Comment: This looks way better than what the OP is doing.  What's a MyZimraHelper?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm assuming a custom class. I just pulled it from the OP to match what he was doing.

Comment: Oh, there it is.  Didn't see it the first time.