# ASP.Net DataGrid Hidden Fields Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

My datagrid contains hidden fields that is causing the datagrid width to expand. I want to keep the hidden fields without the extra spaces that those hidden fields are causing: here is my ASP.NET code for 1 of the hidden fields:

```
    <style>         
.hidden {display:none;}
    </style>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip Code" HeaderText="Zip Code" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
```

This is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

using firebug, this is what I see:
[image]

Comment: Hidenfilds are no displayed on the page at all then how can they cause display issue? There is something else (may be css classes for other elements) in your code causing the issue. May be you have to post the complete code.

Comment: I just updated the question with a screenshot from firebug. What do you think? is that something in my CSS file to show up like this way in firebug? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gridview is set to autogenerate columns. Try setting the `AutoGenerateColumns` property on the gridview to `false` and I think it will render properly.

Comment: nope, I have my AutoGenerateColumns off, I just updated the question with a screenshot from firebug.

Comment: In that case you might consider using a manually coded loop with strongly typed objects in a table rather than a gridview. I touch on that style of looping in [this question about building a list of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149443/alternative-to-innerthtml/25149575#25149575). I'm not sure if your bug is in the gridview itself or if something is screwy with your data, but a loop in the view will fix either of those situations.